# 'overridden method does not throw Exception' when use lambda with override exception thrown

Tags: java, overriding, javac, javacompiler

*To prevent to be closed as duplicate, this question is totally different with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23526362/overridden-method-does-not-throw-exception).*

Consider I have the following interface

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface FuncE0<R, E extends Exception> {
  R call() throws E;
}
```

It works fine with lambda

```
FuncE0<Integer, IOException> get() {
  return () -> 1;
}
```

But if I let the interface extends from `Callable`, it breaks.

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface FuncE0<R, E extends Exception> extends Callable<R> {
  @Override
  R call() throws E;
}
```

With the same usage. Complier gives me following error

```
JustTest.java:8: error: call() in <anonymous JustTest$> cannot implement call() in FuncE0
    return () -> 1;
           ^   overridden method does not throw Exception
```

- If you remove the override method `R call() throws E` in `FuncE0`, it works.
- If you use anonymous class, it works.
- If you use eclipse, ECJ works.

What happened when I override the exception thrown? Is this a javac bug?

*I'm using jdk_1.8_112*

Minimize code to reproduce

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

public class JustTest {
  public static FuncE0<Integer, IOException> get() {
    return () -> 1;
  }

  @FunctionalInterface
  public interface FuncE0<R, E extends Exception> extends Callable<R> {
    @Override
    R call() throws E;
  }
}
```

Comment: your code works for me without any issue

Comment: Compiles fine with jdk-9.0.4 and jdk-10.0.2, but not with jdk1.8.0_181. Also compiles fine with Eclipse Photon compiler, even in Java 8 compatibility mode.

Comment: when using an anonymous class instead of a lambda works in 1.8.0_131

Comment: @Deadpool Which version do you use?

Comment: @Andreas So can I consider it has been fixed in jdk-9?

Comment: for me `java version "1.8.0_171"` it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a jdk bug which has been fixed `1.8.0_171`(may not the lowest fix version).